# jquery slider not working with wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I am trying to integrate  [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) with wordpress and custom content types at [This Link](http://waldondigital.com/strausberg/?page_id=203) .

As you can see by the car images on the right, it's not styling or rotating the images whatsoever. I believe, all the js is in the right place and the CSS isn't being set for the slider. Maybe I'm exhausted, maybe I'm crazy.

Any help would be appreciated, this is driving me nuts. I've been at this for hours.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Skin.css (for the carousel) is before the style.css so style.css looks like it's overriding the skin.css style (because of the cascade rules)

Comment: Reversed the order and there is no change. I don't know why it's not being communicated to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at skin.css, at the very first style:

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    background: #F0F6F9;
    border: 1px solid #346F97;
}
```

In Firebug this style isn't recognized at all, but if you change it to:

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango, .jcarousel-container {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    background: #F0F6F9;
    border: 1px solid #346F97;
}
```

OR:

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    background: #F0F6F9;
    border: 1px solid #346F97;
}
```

Maybe you are just missing the commas "," between the styles on that sheet?